# Save to PDF Page from tab that is unselected keeping it's CSS styling

Tags: html, css, coffeescript, jspdf, html2canvas

Currently, I have managed to convert the currently shown html page to multiple canvas's that are then used to create a multiple paged PDF. The currently shown html page is a tab control with the first tab selected.

However, I also need to get the second tab (currently not selected) into the PDF as well. This includes the formatting of the table itself as normal jsPDF doesn't seem to pull this through.

This second tab is under a ng-show, so it has rendered into the DOM.

I am using a clash of jsPDF and html2canvas to extract the various pages needed for the pdf. However, this is does not work for the content on the unselected tab.

jsPDF can get the data, but completely leaves out the css styling and instead places it's own with mismatched sizing.

The below is an excerpt for a partial retrieval. Which works.

```
  var pdf = new jsPDF({
   orientation: 'landscape'
  });

  html2canvas(sumaryToPDF).then(function(canvas) {
    var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
    pdf.addImage(img, "JPEG", 30, 40, 230, 120);
    pdf.save("my-document.pdf");
  });
```

How can I extract the data with the styling of the unselected tab without actually selecting it?
Once I can extract it, it is fairly simple to place it within the pdf document to save.

Comment: Is there any solution you found for the above issue?

Comment: I couldn't find a way with html2canvas as the page had to be visible and active. jsPDF doesn't take the css from the page, but rather only the data. I had to manually design what was needed when jsPDF was adding the page, plug in the data, and then let it render. It was a hassle as jsPDF does not like charts.